# How do I make a symbol for a second derivative?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting, boxes

In my script, I want the second derivative of a function to be a symbol that I can manipulate (i.e. give a value to, use in an expression, etc.).  So I want to build a box for the expression:$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$Here's what I have so far:

```
MakeBoxes[spaceToTimeSquared, StandardForm] := 
  FractionBox["dx",SuperscriptBox["dt", "2"]];
MakeExpression[FractionBox["dx",SuperscriptBox["dt", "2"]], StandardForm] := 
  MakeExpression["spaceToTimeSquared", StandardForm];
```

I can't figure out the last part, how to combine a superscript with regular text to display the $d^2x$ part.  How do I complete this?

Comment: My apologies.  It's late.  I made the correction.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to represent $d^2 x$ with boxes? If so, just observe `MakeBoxes[TraditionalForm[Dt[x, {t, 2}]]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `RowBox`:

```
MakeBoxes[spaceToTimeSquared, StandardForm] := 
  FractionBox[RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["d", "2"], "x"}], 
   RowBox[{"d", SuperscriptBox["t", "2"]}]];

MakeExpression[
   FractionBox[RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["d", "2"], "x"}], 
    RowBox[{"d", SuperscriptBox["t", "2"]}]], StandardForm] := 
  MakeExpression["spaceToTimeSquared", StandardForm];
```

[image]